# How to compare Chars in C# short way

Tags: c#, char, comparison, character

I'm wondering if there is a short way to compare one Char to many Chars.
In my code I read a Key for Yes or No [Y/N] then i will check if the Char is 'Y' Or 'N'.

This is the Long Way:

```
if(myChar == 'n' || myChar == 'y')
{
....
```

It tried(didn't work):

```
if(myChar == ('n'|'y'))
{
.....
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I mean, if its just two expressions I don't see why you would need any short hand.  An alternative would be to have an array of "allowed chars" and do a `Contains()`, but that seems overkill for something like this.

Comment: The long way is the best way in this case, imo.

Answer (score 4):

Try looking in a *collection*:

```
HashSet<char> valid = new HashSet<char>() {
  'y', 'n', 'N', 'Y',
};

...

if (valid.Contains(myChar)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why not just a string instead of a Hashset?

Comment: @Kenneth K.: quite right, `if ("nNyY".Contains(myChar))`{...}` is possible, but I prefer `HashSet<char>` for its *readability* (we have a collection of *valid* characters; if we want to add, say `T` `t` for true we know what to do)

Comment: @GiladGreen Agreed, but O(1) for 4 characters isn't going to be very much of an impact.

Comment: Is it wrong to use: if ("ny".Contains(myChar.ToString().ToLower()))?

Comment: @Sean Stayn: it should be `if ("ny".Contains(char.ToLower(myChar))) {...}`

Comment: Am I taking crazy pills?  Or is a "Y/N" check really need to be this complex?  Haha

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Actually, if you want to be proper it should be `if ("ny".Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(myChar)))`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: Agree; one should put `Invariant` in order to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

When the list of characters is short, use `Contains` method of `string`:

```
if ("yn".Contains(myChar)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note, this will be a case sensitive compare. You will need to do `"YyNn".Contains(myChar)` or use `"yn".IndexOf(myChar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is absolutely true, if OP needs case-insensitive comparison, he would need to do one of the methods that you described.